# How to delete an object store on Persisten Object on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have a class with name DataContext that use Hashtable to save data to Persistent Object.
Example I save two object:

```
DataContext data = new DataContext();
data.set("object1", EditField1.getText();
data.set("object2", EditField2.getText();
data.commit();
```

I only want to delete data of "object1" ( not delete data of "object2" ), so i can not use data.clear();
I make like this code:

```
if(data.get("object1")!=null){
data.set("object1",null);
data.commit();
}
```

But I received error " App Error 104 NullPointerExceptions ".
How I can to delete data of "object1" ?
Please help me.

---

Binh - VietNam

Comment: plese specify your wraper class

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove an element from a Hashtable then use the [remove()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/util/Hashtable.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) method of your hashtable object.